# Grub problems on dual boot windows 10 / ubuntu 16.04 laptop using samsung 950 pro ssd's

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, ssd

I have been googling like crazy to solve this issue and most of the posted solutions have failed.

I am trying to dual boot an Alienware 17 R3 computer that came with Windows 10 preinstalled on a 1TB HDD. I installed 2 Samsung 950 Pro SSD's and I have previously managed to get Ubuntu 16.04 installed and it dual booted fine.

However, I upgraded the BIOS and that caused serious problems with (only) the Ubuntu installation. First it was a nouveau error and then it dropped me to a shell because it couldn't find the boot drive (I think) I figured that the sanest step was to re-format the SSD's and do a fresh reinstall of Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB.

I have turned off Fast Boot and Secure Boot and have used the UEFI boot with Legacy Option ROM. I cannot recall exactly if Secure Boot was disabled during the initial installation of Ubuntu but I can say with certainty that, as of this moment, Ubuntu (and gparted) do not recognize my SSD drives without Secure Boot being deactivated. With Secure Boot acitvated, I am unable to install to, or even find the SSDs using 'sudo fdisk -l'. As I mentioned previously, I don't think this was the case during the first install (prior to the BIOS update) but I can't be certain.

I am still booted from the USB in UEFI mode and installed in UEFI mode. The installation seemingly went well and advised me to reboot, but the reboot takes me to the grub rescue page ('no such device' then the UUID for the SSD that has the root info).

I tried running boot-repair (several times) but that was ineffective. The latest output can be seen here: http://paste2.org/7LOvctjf

It appears as though this BIOS update has done something to Ubuntu's ability to find/recognize my SSD's, yet it was previously able to do so.

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated. I am able to get into Ubuntu via the USB so please let me know what further information is required to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Paul

p.s. the BIOS update also create a 'nouveau' error but that seems like it has to do with nvidia drivers and is probably unrelated to the larger problem. I only mention it in case it is more meaningful than I believe.

Comment: Do you have 2 NMVe drives and a HDD? You also may need a kernel update. Kernel 4.6 has Dell & Alienware improvements including 9350
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-4.6-Laptop-Drivers You can use a ppa to get newer kernels. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds And you may need the newer gparted. gparted should be at least version 0.24.0-1 to recognize NVMe devices
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/index.php

Comment: Thanks for the tips oldfred! I was using gparted 0.25.0-1 (which comes with Ubuntu 16.04) so that wasn't the issue. When investigating the potential kernel update issue, I was able to update to 4.6.3 (latest non-RC) release using Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater without errors, but after running 'uname -a' it still said the kernel was 4.4.0-21. I think this is due to the fact that I am running off the Ubuntu USB so I might need to do it manually to see if I can get it to change the kernel on the nvme drive.

Comment: I think some Dell need Legacy option on in BIOS, but you still can boot in UEFI boot mode to install in UEFI mode. Not sure how that works as I thought UEFI & BIOS were totally separate.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I've heard that secure boot support to linux is kinda experimental stuff...
You could try these:
0) Turn off secure boot
1) Download Windows 10 installation media:
2) Follow the steps to fix windows boot. https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader
It says windows 8, but I think it's the same on Windows 10.
3) Re-install linux, on EFI, without the Legacy Option. To know if you are on correct mode, it boots direct to grub-like menu.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Cloaker. I did as you said but Ubuntu still could not detect the SSD's while the Legacy option was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I bought Alienware 17 R3 june 2016 with win 10 pro, it came with 128gb m.2 ssd with windows 10 pro installed on it and a 1 tb 7200rpm drive ,as a data dirve. 
1. I partitioned the 128gb m.2 ssd in half and
created a usb efi boot ubuntu 16.04 with rufus in windows
2. rebooted into bios boot by tapping i think F12 and selected the option USB uefi boot (or something like that cant remember exactly) and it installed ubuntu 16.04 ok and am able to duel boot win10 & ubuntu. I will say ubuntu 16.04 has issues with AW17R3 , had to install linux-firware 1.158 to get Killer networks wireless working. Small issue with Creative soundblaster earphone output drivers being a little buggy. BEing duel video cards Intel skylake & Nvidia 970m ,you can install nvidia drivers and the intel proprietary driver that ubuntu offers..but I ran into issues with 361 nvidia driver and the ability to switch between Nvidia & Intel  using "Prime select" causes instability bigtime. Ended up having to apt-get remove Nvidia , I did apt-get purge nvidia as well and things worked fine since

Shred