# Noobie Grub2 Dual boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I bought a Alienware 15 R2 back in September with the intention of dual booting between Windows 10 and Ubuntu. My plan was to install Ubuntu on a 64GB micro sdcard, there is a slot built in. The installation went through just fine, but it boots straight to Windows 10. I've gone into the BIOS and I see that the installer created a UBUNTU entry, but when I set it to the primary bootloader it just goes to a command prompt that show "grub>".

The grub.cfg file only has 1 line in it which points to my main hard drive that has Windows installed. The line is as follows:

```
search.fs_uuid ********-****-****-************ root set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

When I change the uuid to that of the sdcard it does the same thing.

The reason I'm trying to have the OS on the sdcard is so that I can make better use of my hard space. When I first got the laptop I did let the installer partition the drive, but after a warranty fix for a defective video card. I figured better to make use of the sdcard slot, since I had a 64GB card laying around still unopened.

I'm a Cisco network admin by trade and I've installed Windows plenty of times and only played with Ubuntu a handful of times, but my god this stuff is not something one can just pickup. I've spent months searching and I still do not understand how this bootloader works at all. Its extremely frustrating.

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: It may be a limitation of the boot process that SD card drivers are not loaded until later. If it dual-boots from a USB drive, but not the SD card, that could be the issue. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromSD , though.

Comment: Did you partition in advance with gpt including the ESP - efi system partition? Not sure if UEFI will boot sdcard as external as that has to be /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, not an internal command. http://askubuntu.com/questions/795755/grub-problems-on-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-using-samsung-950-pr and:http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu