# Ubuntu Mate 17.04 and Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, mate

I have dual booted my laptop with following configuration:

1. SSD - Windows 10 Professional. Single partition.
2. HDD - 5 partitions. 3 for windows and 2 for Ubuntu (mount - / and swap area).

My problem is that post  successful installation of Ubuntu. After logging into Ubuntu (mate 17.04) the screen is static. Mouse cursor is moving but I can't see any icons or carry out any actions (no taskbar / start / menus / etc.).

My laptop is Dell Alienware 17 R4.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What video? You may need video driver. This is an R3 and the issues found there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/795755/grub-problems-on-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-using-samsung-950-pr

Comment: I have Nvidia 1060 GTX. Should i download the "run" package from Nvidia and try and install it using terminal mode (by selecting advance options during boot)? If so will the "run" file directly install or is there an apt-get method to do this too.

Comment: Do not download .run from nVidia. You in effect have to reinstall with every kernel update. If you need newest nVidia driver you an add a ppa that has all those drivers configured to work with Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers If you already installed, this includes purge instructions so you can reinstall. Do not attempt to install a second driver without purging old driver first. Major conflict will occur as second install does not delete older version.