# Install Ubuntu on Alienware 15 R3 without disturbing Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have Alienware 15 R3 with:

- 512GB NVME SSD - Windows 10.
- 1TB HDD - 300GB free space available.

I would like to install Ubuntu using the free space available in 1TB HDD.

I have experience installing Dual Boot Ubuntu on my old laptop, but after a Windows 10 auto-update, the boot loader got corrupted.

So, how should I install Ubuntu without disturbing anything that links to Windows Boot?

Comment: If Windows 10, it is the newer UEFI and you will want Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Is HDD gpt partitioned? Best to always back up before any major system change. Only use Something Else install option. Another Alienware install: https://askubuntu.com/questions/795755/grub-problems-on-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-using-samsung-950-pr &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: select the "Use freespace"

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Live-CD when detects another system, it gives the option to install Ubuntu at side of Windows 10. It does everything to you (installs the system in the free space and installs grub too).

So, first of all, you should change the BIOS settings to boot first the Live-CD than the Windows Bootloader (I'm assuming here you've alredy prepared an USB with the Ubuntu Live CD)

After this, you plug the USB and turn on the PC. During the installation, it will detect the Windows installed and will offer you to install Ubuntu at side of Windows 10. Select this and proceed the installation. It will install Ubuntu and grub. That's all! When you turn on PC after the installation, grub will ask what system to boot.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below link and was able to install ubuntu 17.10 as dual boot with the original windows 10

https://gist.github.com/awesomebytes/e4556b06bedf860189378428b508c043