# Can't Install 18.04 on Alienware 13 R3

Tags: system-installation

I am unable to install 18.04 on my Alienware 13 R3 as the installer hangs after a random amount of time. The installer will actually work if I plug an external gpu into the laptop but without the egpu it hangs. I honestly have no idea why since I had no issues with 16.04.

Comment: have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Is drive set for AHCI, unless RAID 0. What video card? If nVidia, you need nomodeset boot parameter until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. Some other Alienware threads: https://askubuntu.com/questions/795755/grub-problems-on-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-16-04-laptop-using-samsung-950-pr & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2311390&p=13430555#post13430555 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2313054

Comment: I am on the latest BIOS. The drive is set to AHCI. Specs below. I have tried installing the nvidia driver from the unbuntu repository. I haven't tried the boot parameter yet, I will give that a shot.

GPU: GTX 1060
CPU: i7 7700HQ
SSD0: Toshiba 512GB NVME - Included with laptop
SSD1: Samsung 960 EVO NVME 1TB

Comment: After using the bootflag I was able to install the missing nvidia driver that was causing the issue. After some light googling this issue might be cause by intel dropping support after 16.04.

Comment: So `nomodeset` fixed the issue for you when installing Ubuntu?